# Copy by keypress, Paste by keyrelease

Tags: macos, keyboard, copy-paste

Is there a way in MacOS(BigSur or later) to program a certain native keyboard key to behave as Copy(cmd-c) when pressed and Paste(cmd-v) when released?

Sequence description:
0. Start script/app to configure the copy paste key once(for example at boot)

1. select text (as you usual do before copy)
2. press the configured key for the copy action and keep it pressed
3. point where you want to paste (as you usual do)
4. release the key pressed at step 2.

I have this working in the iCue Corsair keyboard software. I like to have this available in with the native MBP-keyboard. Hope this explains what I'm looking for.

Comment: How would it know where to paste?

Comment: Or even when/what to copy

Comment: Maybe add a picture or a sequence describing the problem you are automating or speeding up. If you press a key to copy and then paste, that does nothing since the paste replaces the selection with itself. This is a non-operation, so just don’t press the key, same result.

Comment: So we are talking about a non-character key (or a combo)?

Comment: yes, that would be the way to go. On my Corsair I have programmable macro keys I used with the iCue software